# Attributing resubscribes to an in-app without obfuscatedAccountId

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-subscription, google-play-developer-api

This question is similar to [Google play store does not return obfuscatedExternalAccountId when resubscribing after expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69762817/google-play-store-does-not-return-obfuscatedexternalaccountid-when-resubscribing), but there are some concerns I have that aren't fully addressed (and I don't have the reputation to comment).

Suppose `google-user-1` purchase a subscription on my app, on the account `app-user-1`. This subscription is later cancelled and expires naturally. In the mean time, `google-user-1` has created a new in app account and logged in to `app-user-2`. `google-user-1` then resubscribes via the Play
Store.

According to the answer I posted above, I am forced to wait for `google-user-1` to access my app, then I can attribute the resubscribe to whichever in-app user that `google-user-1` is logged in.

I foresee two concerns.

- The resubscribe event gave a subscription to `app-user-2` rather than `app-user-1`. This could be a concern if subscriptions have history, e.g. users with subscriptions at time X receive reward Y and this reward persists as long as you have a subscription (even with a gap in subscription). `app-user-1` has this reward but `app-user-2` does not.
- If the Google user does not log in to my app within 3 days, the purchase will be refunded because my app cannot acknowledge the purchase - because the purchase has not been tied to an in-app user yet. (Perhaps they don't actually want the subscription if they haven't logged in by then)

What are common resolutions to the above problems?